# Run iMacros in Firefox via Python

Tags: python, firefox, imacros

I have process that uses iMacros in Firefox to open some websites and click on some buttons and do some stuff (not any weird stuff, internal work pages). The problem is that I basically can't use my computer while that happens.

I want to automate this via python and found this:

[Integrating iMacros scripts into python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11990723/integrating-imacros-scripts-into-python)

However the answer to that question and the links mention that I need the business or enterprise version of it.

Is there a way to just do something like:

- Open firefox (I know how)
- Use (as a  plugin) iMacros to run a iim script in x location

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have 100% control over Firefox with Python, as both are open source. The trick is to figure out details. Here are some starting points

- Python can script Firefox with [Selenium WebDriver](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html)
- With some tricks, you can dive deeper into Firefox what basic Selenium interaction offers, like opening a web pages. This would include giving direct commands to plugins. [Here is an example of settings Firefox profile in a mode that normal security restrictions do not apply](https://github.com/miohtama/Krusovice/blob/master/bin/create_bg_thumbnails.py#L103).
- You need to study Firefox architecture how you can trigger iMacros plugin commands from Selenium. This is the tricky part as this is very marginal use case and there might not be much information available. Expect spending few days of learning Firefox internals.

My guess is that you can disable Firefox security, and then use Selenium WebDriver to run a JavaScript snippet which gives direct commands to iMacros component.

Comment: Hi! I'm marking this as the answer since it introduced selenium for me and will very likely make my life easier in the future. However the easy solution was to use `subprocess` to make firefox run this: `subprocess.call([r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe', '-new-tab', 'imacros://run/?m=Demo-Firefox%5CTabs.iim'])` after bookmarking the iim file in firefox :)

Comment: @rodrigocf: Cool stuff :)